# How to use a nuget package that has no library in it but only files to be used

Tags: c#, nuget

I have installed a nuget package (say 'foo', version=1.0.4) in my C# project that only has some data files in it and no library, that's why it can't be referenced in the project. The files are located at the nuget package's default location (`{proj loc}\packages\foo.1.0.4\lib\net45\`). How can I properly access/read these files in C# code?

I know that I can access them by specifying their physical path on the disk, e.g.

```
string filePath = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))}\\packages\\foo.1.0.4\\lib\net45\\bar.ttf";
```

But I don't want to do that as part of the path is hard-coded and that will change whenever a newer version of the 'foo' nuget package (i.e. this part '\foo.1.0.4\') is installed.

**UPDATE:**
I've figured out a fully dynamic solution, Please see it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459367/1300390

Comment: Why you need a Nuget for data files? that's looks like wrong use of it

Comment: There can be a no. of scenarios where using nuget package can prove to be quite efficient and smart for non lib files, for example in our case, those files are generated by another project and a no. of other client projects need to include/use those files if they need them along with availing the opportunity to get their updated versions as and when they are available, and nuget package management provides a well organized mechanism in this case. All I need to know is how to properly access those files that are downloaded by the nuget package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with different approaches and attempts, finally I figured out the following one that quite nicely solves this problem:

The files from the nuget package's default download folder can be accessed/read without defining any varying hard-coded part as:

```
string appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
string filePath = Directory.GetFiles(appDir, "baar.ttf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).First();
```

**UPDATE:**

To make it a bit more faster, the search space can be reduced further to the 'packages' folder only, as:

```
string nugetPackagesDir = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))}\\packages";
string filePath = Directory.GetFiles(nugetPackagesDir, "baar.ttf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).First();
```

Comment: be careful as this is fragile. The directory of nuget packages can be configured to be something else or the package can be installed globally.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is depending on an external resource which is subject to changes, you should consider creating a directory in your project root.

MyProj
 - MyTiffStorage (New folder)

And change your code accordingly to point to this directory.
But in this case you need to be mindful to copy the files from the package (...lib\net45) whenever there is an update to the package.

This way for your code there is always a single source of truth and so the code need not change each time there is an update. However as mentioned be mindful to copy the files manually.

Thank You

Comment: @"But in this case you need to be mindful to copy the files from the package (...lib\net45) whenever there is an update to the package."

Copying files from the nuget package's default download dir '{proj loc}\packages\foo.1.0.4\lib\net45\' is not nice and easy as this path with change every time the nuget package will be updated to a newer version (as I already hinted this issue in my question)

Comment: I saw your answer. You are trying to do a directory search for the file. Have you considered the performance measures associated with this approach. Since I can't comment your answer I am writing it here.

Comment: Its quite strange to learn that you can't comment under my answer!
Anyways, yes I have considered that, its a one time file search operation within the application directory which should usually be quite fast (though it depends upon the size of your app directory)

Comment: Btw, keeping in view the point you raised, I've made an update to my answer

Comment: Cool. I don't think I have the required amount of stack overflow points to comment on an answer which isnt mine.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> There can be a no. of scenarios where using nuget package can prove to
>   be quite efficient and smart for non lib files, for example in our
>   case, those files are generated by another project and a no. of other
>   client projects need to include/use those files if they need them
>   along with availing the opportunity to get their updated versions as
>   and when they are available, and nuget package management provides a
>   well organized mechanism in this case.

One solution is to create a thin layer library with an interface to access those files (package it in the same nuget).

An alternate route to consider if you are using git is to use submodules instead of nuget packages. If this is viable depends on your specific workflow.

Comment: your first suggestion (of thin lib) is a very good approach which I also thought, but there seems to be problems with it, as the source nuget package is php based web project, so I'm not sure if php can offer a lib that a c# project can reference